# woocommerce_order_itemmeta value empty for sub order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my order, order item meta table values are 0. Please check the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more info in order for someone to help you. Show how you set up the woocommerce_order_itemmeta and what you've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @Yep_It's_Me https://staging.rareitis.com/checkout/order-received/32094/?key=wc_order_59783cb056f83, the above link is the order recived page. Please check the link above. You may see suborder have price and quantity values are zero

Comment: I don't see any suborder, price or quantity? and nothing is 0?

Comment: The problem was with Dokan multivendor plugin, It create suborder if the product are from diffrent seller and the product Id left as blank and it became threre as 0. That's why main order does't contains 0 and sub orders have 0. I have found solution that related with dokan.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it to help others with the same problem.

Comment: That issue was relaed with dokan plugin. It wont't send eny value before. I have added the following code to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related with Dokan Plugin. Dokan will create suborder automatically based on seller.

Added the following code inside wp-contents/plugins/[dokan]/includes/wc-functions.php

```
    function dokan_get_order_item_meta_map() {
    return apply_filters( 'dokan_get_order_item_meta_keymap', array(
        'product_id'   => '_product_id',
        'variation_id' => '_variation_id',
        'quantity'     => '_qty',
        'tax_class'    => '_tax_class',
        'subtotal'     => '_line_subtotal',
        'subtotal_tax' => '_line_subtotal_tax',
        'total'        => '_line_total',
        'total_tax'    => '_line_tax',
        'taxes'        => '_line_tax_data'
    ) );
}
```

Also modifyed the function 
`function dokan_create_seller_order( $parent_order, $seller_id, $seller_products )`

and changed the section after that
 `if ($itemid){` to

```
if ( $item_id ) {
                $item_meta_data = $item->get_data();
                $meta_key_map = dokan_get_order_item_meta_map();
                foreach ( $item->get_extra_data_keys() as $meta_key ) {
                    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $meta_key_map[$meta_key], $item_meta_data[$meta_key] );
                }
```

Now the product meta data will save to the correspon